# Use/reference container name in a different service with docker compose

Tags: mongodb, docker, docker-compose, mongo-express

My `docker-compose.yml` file looks like this:

```
version: '3.7'

networks: 
  myNetwork:

volumes:
  mongo_data:

services:

  db:
    image: mongo
    restart: always
    networks: 
      - myNetwork
    volumes: 
      - mongo_data:/data/db
    ports: 
        - "27017:27017"

  mongoExpress:
    image: mongo-express
    networks: 
      - myNetwork
    ports:
      - "8081:8081"
    environment: 
      - ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_SERVER=<db-container-name>
    depends_on: 
      - db
```

For `mongo-express` to work, I need to be able to pass it the `db`/`mongo` container name. Is there a way to achieve this with compose?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The service name is the host name on the network (`myNetwork`)  created by compose.

You may use `db` as the host name and value for `<db-container-name>`

i.e.

```
ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_SERVER=db
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. How does this work? When I do a docker inspect on the container for `db` the hostname field is not `db`. It's something like `f7c3f437315a`

Comment: You're welcome. You're asking a question that would require a lengthy answer and is best addressed by Docker's networking docs. Have a look here for starters: https://docs.docker.com/network/

Comment: I did read through the docs before asking the question but couldn't find anything. Would you mind pointing me to the part in that document that you're referring to?

Comment: I wasn't referring to a specific section. You can enumerate the networks (`docker network ls`) and then `docker inspect ${ID}` to see which containers are bound to the network. Docker provides a DNS service (look at the `/etc/resolv.conf` in a container) and you should be able to e.g. `nslookup db` to see that this resolves to the appropriate container network subnet. HTH!

Comment: Yeah, the `nslookup` definitely helps.